# playback speed is slow

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

When I listen to music on Youtube ,I realised the music sounds a little wired. I feel playback speed becomes slower than I heard before, even if playback speed in video setting is normal. So I used stopwatch installed on ubuntu to see whether the speed become slow.Then I discover video playback speed really has that problem. After that , I tried to play music on different stream platform and use media player to play local music file. I found they all have the same problem.
Ubuntu version is 20.04.4 LTS
How can I fix it?

Comment: Please [edit] the question and post hardware specifications, namely graphics.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was resolved after installing an update. XD THX